# React Native error ModuleResolver.resolveDependency

Tags: react-native

I am receiving this error and I can't figure out what's causing it because when I navigate to a different screen, everything is working properly. If it's a package error then I would know as it usually will point out which line but I really have no idea how to navigate this kind or error log.

```
None of these files exist:
  * http:\localhost:8081\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * http:\localhost:8081\index\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1072:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:428:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (D:\REACT NATIVE\app-test\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:380:9)
```

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the cause of this error. It appears that my server side has issue. I have it fixed and it's not showing anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when dependency cycles exist in the codebase. Have you tried to enable `"import/no-cycle"` rule in your eslint config file and detect the existing cycles? Maybe could help to figure out why this error occurs...

[For more informations regarding eslint import/no-cycle](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md)

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory, where all the files are kept, because in my instance I accidentally put a new js file in the assets folder, and it took me around 30 minutes to realise my error after browsing the internet and chatgpt.